# Download manager in Chrome comparable to that in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

In Firefox, I can select multiple links to files such as pdf in a webpage, then right click and choose download-selection, or simply without selecting anything, right click and choose download-them-all. I wonder how I can do the same in Chrome? I cannot find equivalence there. Thanks!

Comment: The Firefox behaviour you're talking about isn't standard (at least not in my copy of Firefox 10). Probably an addon such as DownThemAll? Unfortunately, DownThemAll does not have and do not plan to have support for Chrome, but others have suggested extensions such as [Download Master](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mcceagdollnkjlogmdckgjakjapmkdjf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not by default, but the [Link Clump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj) extensions that lets you do this.